# not-null property references a null value while adding new user with foreign key

Tags: spring, hibernate, spring-mvc, jsp, jpa

I'm trying to insert a new user to the database , which contains a foreign key to userRole . i populated a roles dropdown list in jsp from the database , inserted in a form in which I'll add a new user . i'm really blocked for days now ... user also has a primary key.

```html
org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request processing failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.PropertyValueException: not-null property references a null or transient value: jpa.project.model.DemUser.idRole
```

Role entity :

```
@Entity
@Table(name="DEM_ROLE")
@NamedQuery(name="DemRole.findAll", query="SELECT d FROM DemRole d")
public class DemRole implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private long idRole;
    private String libRole;
    private String librole;

    public DemRole() {
    }


    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name="ID_ROLE", unique=true, nullable=false)
    public long getIdRole() {
        return this.idRole;
    }

    public void setIdRole(long idRole) {
        this.idRole = idRole;
    }


    @Column(name="LIB_ROLE", nullable=false, length=50)
    public String getLibRole() {
        return this.libRole;
    }

    public void setLibRole(String libRole) {
        this.libRole = libRole;
    }


    @Column(length=255)
    public String getLibrole() {
        return this.librole;
    }

    public void setLibrole(String librole) {
        this.librole = librole;
    }

}
```

User Entity :

```html
@Entity
@Table(name="DEM_USER")
@NamedQuery(name="DemUser.findAll", query="SELECT d FROM DemUser d")
public class DemUser implements Serializable {
 private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

 @Id
 @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
 @Column(name="ID_USER", unique=true, nullable=false)
 private long idUser;

 @Column(name="NAME_USER", nullable=false, length=50)
 private String nameUser;

 @Column(nullable=false, length=20)
 private String password;

 //uni-directional many-to-one association to DemRole
 @ManyToOne(cascade={CascadeType.ALL},fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
 @JoinColumn(name="ID_ROLE", nullable=false)
 private DemRole idRole;

 public DemUser() {
 }

 public long getIdUser() {
  return this.idUser;
 }

 public void setIdUser(long idUser) {
  this.idUser = idUser;
 }

 public String getNameUser() {
  return this.nameUser;
 }

 public void setNameUser(String nameUser) {
  this.nameUser = nameUser;
 }

 public String getPassword() {
  return this.password;
 }

 public void setPassword(String password) {
  this.password = password;
 }

 public DemRole getIdRole() {
  return this.idRole;
 }

 public void setIdRole(DemRole idRole) {
  this.idRole = idRole;
 }

}

<!-- begin snippet: js hide: false console: true babel: false -->
```

Controller :

```html
 @RequestMapping(value = "/",method = RequestMethod.GET)
 public ModelAndView home(ModelAndView model,HttpServletRequest request) throws IOException {
     List<DemUser> listUsers = service.getAllUsers();
  model.addObject("listUsers", listUsers);  
  
  List<DemRole> listRoles = service.getRoles();
  request.setAttribute("listRoles", listRoles);
  /*List<DemRole> listRoles = service.getRoles();
  model.addObject("listRoles", listRoles);  */
  
  DemUser user = new DemUser();
  model.addObject("DemUser", user); 
    
  model.setViewName("manageusers");
  return model;
 }
 @RequestMapping(value = "/actionadduser", method = RequestMethod.POST)
 public String actionadduser(ModelAndView model,@ModelAttribute DemRole role ,@ModelAttribute DemUser user,BindingResult result) {

        service.addUser(user);
  return "redirect:/";
 }
```

JSP :

```html
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"
   "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
   <%@ taglib prefix="form" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form"%>
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="sec" uri="http://www.springframework.org/security/tags" %>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>
     <div align="left">
This is manage users
<table border="1">
        <h1>users</h1>
   <tr><td> Names : </td> </tr>
   <c:forEach var="user" items="${listUsers}">
    <tr>
     <td>${user.nameUser}</td>   
    </tr>
   </c:forEach>
  </table>
       </div>
       
       
      <div align="right">
        <h1>New user</h1>
        <form:form action="actionadduser" method="post" modelAttribute="DemUser">
        <table>
                    <form:hidden path="idUser" />
                     <form:hidden path="password" value="password" />
            <tr>
                <td>Name:</td>
                <td><form:input path="nameUser" /></td>
            </tr>
        <tr>
    <td>Roles :</td>
    <td>
    <form:select path="idRole">
         <form:options items="${listRoles}"  itemValue="idRole" itemLabel="libRole"></form:options>
    </form:select></td>

</tr>
            <tr>
                <td colspan="2" align="center"><input type="submit" value="Save"></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
        </form:form>
        </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are couple of points,

1. As roles already exist before adding a new User, So you don't need to have any type of cascading in @ManyToOne mapping, you can remove cascading at all.

```
    //uni-directional many-to-one association to DemRole
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="ID_ROLE", nullable=false)
    private DemRole idRole;
```

2. I can see in your POST method, you are receiving DemRole and DemUser and calling the service class to persist the user, but I can't see anywhere that you are populating the received role object into received user object. As User is having Role object, so before saving user object, you need to have something like this,

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/actionadduser", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String actionadduser(ModelAndView model,@ModelAttribute DemRole role ,@ModelAttribute DemUser user,BindingResult result) {

        // set role object to user object
        user.setIdRole(role); // setter for DemRole object.
        service.addUser(user);
        return "redirect:/";
    }
```

Hope this helps, please let me know if any more clarifications are needed.

Comment: Thanks a lot bro , it worked , guess imma get to know more about @ModelAttribute thing and how to use it ..